# all() returns different values for the same expression

Tags: python

I'm facing a very weird problem in my python script when I use the function `all()`.

The console gives me `false` (which is obviously correct) for this line:

```
all(x == 2 for x in (8,2,2,2))
```

and in my script the same line returns `true`?!

What is going on here? Are there other `all()` function which could have overwritten it in my script? I'm importing the following modules:

```
import os
import sys
import string
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime
from optparse import OptionParser, OptionGroup
import cx_Oracle
from pylab import *
import ROOT
from array import array
import logging
from traceback import format_exc
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing your script to just those imports and the ``all()`` line? If so, it's got to be ``pylab`` smashing ``all()`` - as that's the only one importing stuff into your main namespace.

Comment: Well, it does return false in my case. With few imports removed.

Comment: Add `print (all)` to your code. You should see `<built-in function all>`

Comment: OK I got it thanks! `from pylab import *` overwrites it. How can I access the built-in `all()` function?

Comment: @GaryvanderMerwe +1 - best method of testing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the builtin `all()` when it's being smashed, you can import [`builtins`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/builtins.html). E.g:

```
from builtins import all
```

(Below the line where `pylab` is imported).

Alternatively, if you need to access `pylab.all()`, you can do:

```
import builtins

...

builtins.all()
```

Or, better yet, do `import pylab` rather than `from pylab import *`.

You might want to file a bug report with `pylab` too, that's seriously bad behaviour. Although do note the `import * from ...` usage of imports is discouraged for this reason.

As DSM points out in the comments, this is presuming you are using 3.x, under 2.x, it is `__builtin__`.

Comment: Is there a way to access `all()` directly, without overwriting it again?

Comment: @septi You could do ``import builtins`` then ``builtins.all()``.

Comment: That'll work in Python 3, but not in Python 2.  `import __builtin__` or just `__builtins__.all()` should work in 2.X (at least >= 2.5, which is all I have at hand to check.)

Comment: @DSM Good shout, didn't realise this was a 3.x feature.

Comment: Thanks : ) I changed the line to `import pylab`…

Comment: @Lattyware I do not consider this “seriously bad behavior”.  It is handy and convenient in interactive sessions and likely intended for this very purpose.  Outside of interactive sessions wildcard imports should not be used anyway.  Likely the Pylab developers will discard any bug reports about this based on the same reasoning.

Comment: @lunaryorn Generally it's good practice to avoid smashing built-in names, using a synonym or ``all_()`` would have been a better choice. But yeah, unless they recommend using ``from pylab import *`` it's probably not as bad as I made out.

Comment: @Lattyware You avoid smashing (built-in) names by either explicitly importing these or using qualified names, that is **proper use and separation of namespaces**.  Symbol pre- or postfixes are for languages without those, e.g. C.  If users break through namespace separation by wildcard imports, it's their fault.